# can't convert Array into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, chef-infra

I have the following command in my `recipes/default.rb`:

```
 data = data_bag_item('config','info')

 bash "setup_hadoop" do
   user "#{node[:cluster][:user]}"
   group "#{node[:cluster][:user]}"
   cwd "#{node[:cluster][:home]}"
   code <<-EOF
     wget http://apache.mirror.gtcomm.net/hadoop/common/hadoop-1.2.1/hadoop-1.2.1.tar.gz
     tar -xzvf hadoop-1.2.1.tar.gz
     mv hadoop-1.2.1 hadoop
   EOF

    template "#{node[:cluster][:hadoop]}/hadoop-env.sh" do
       source "hadoop-env.sh.erb"
       mode 0755
       owner "#{node[:cluster][:user]}"
       group "#{node[:cluster][:user]}"
       variables( :cluster_size => data['cluster_size'] )
   end
```

and I have the json file `info.json` in `/data_bag/config/`:

```
{
   "id": "info",
   "cluster_size": 2
}
```

However, when I try to make use of the data bag, I got the following error:

```
[2014-05-05T14:35:45+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2014-05-05T14:35:45+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2014-05-05T14:35:45+00:00] ERROR: Failed to load data bag item: "config" "info"

================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /tmp/vagrant-chef-6/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/cluster/recipes/default.rb
================================================================================


TypeError
---------
can't convert Array into String


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /tmp/vagrant-chef-6/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/cluster/recipes/default.rb:10:in `from_file'


Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/tmp/vagrant-chef-6/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/cluster/recipes/default.rb:
    TypeError
    ---------
can't convert Array into String
 10>> data = data_bag_item('config','info')
 11:  
 12:  bash "setup_hadoop" do
 13:     user "#{node[:cluster][:user]}"
 14:     group "#{node[:cluster][:user]}"
 15:     cwd "#{node[:cluster][:home]}"
 16:     code <<-EOF
 17:     wget http://apache.mirror.gtcomm.net/hadoop/common/hadoop-1.2.1/hadoop-1.2.1.tar.gz
 18:     tar -xzvf hadoop-1.2.1.tar.gz
 19:     mv hadoop-1.2.1 hadoop
 20:     variables( :cluster_size => data['cluster_size'] )
```

to make sure the data bag is correctly loaded, I ran:

```
knife data bag show config info
cluster_size: 2
id:           info
```

Which seems correctly. Could someone please help me out? I followed [this](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_data_bags.html) tutorial to create the data bag.

Comment: Why are you doing `"#{node[:cluster][:user]}"` instead of just `node[:cluster][:user]`?

Comment: What specifically are you doing that you are getting this error?

Comment: @JustinWood I'm running `vagrant up --provider=aws` but that's the code pretty much ... and for your first question I'm replacing a variable inside a string

Comment: Could you add the relevant portion of the stack trace? After all this is StackOverflow, no?

Comment: @Patru I will do it in a second

Comment: Please don't post code with line numbers, it is a problem for us to take the code and run on our editors.. You are putting us to do some double and unnecessary work..

Comment: Please post the code from the beginning of the file

Comment: @UriAgassi I post all the code.

Comment: `data = ...` is the first line in your code? the stack trace suggests that it is line #10...

Comment: @UriAgassi the first 9 lines are just comment lines for the file header ... talks about dev, email support, cookbook version, etc etc ...